# How to push everything to GitHub except one file

Tags: git, github

I want to push my whole project to GitHub except sql.py.

I have two remotes, actually, one to a shared network drive (that should continue to get the updated sql.py), and one to GitHub which has more privacy restrictions.

I tried making a .gitignore but this has the consequence of

1. always ignoring sql.py
2. also my file somehow went missing recently (receovered it with a backup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply stage all files except for `sql.py`

#### Add all files

`git add --all`

#### Unstage the file you want to exclude

```
git reset HEAD -- sql.py
```

#### Commit your file

```
git commit -m "All project files"
```